# Webflux: Extract body from Request

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I would like to validate the request body. If the body is valid, the doSomething(..) method should be called with valueDTO and HTTP 200 is returned.
If validation fails, HTPP 403 is returned.

Code as follows:

```
@Override
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> job(Mono<ValueDTO> valueDTO, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
  
  // extract dataBuffer from Request
  Flux<DataBuffer> data = exchange.getRequest().getBody();

  return DataBufferUtils.join(data)
      .map(
          dataBuffer -> {
            // extract body from request
            CharBuffer charBuffer = StandardCharset.UTF_8.decode(dataBuffer.asByteBuffer());
            DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
            return charBuffer.toString();
          })
      .zipWith(valueDTO) // zip with valueDTO
      .flatMap( tuple -> {
        if (validateBody(tuple.getT1())) {
          doSomething(tuple.getT2()).then(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok()));
        }
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(403).build());
      });

}

private boolean validateBody(String body) {
  // ommited
}

private Mono<Void> doSomething(valueDTO) {
  // omitted
}
```

I'm getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one connection receive subscriber allowed.
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.subscribe(FluxReceive.java:171)
```

for the zipWith. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about `I would like extract the body from the Request and access the Mono "down the chain` what mono? everything is a mono, you have several monos, i dont get it. `myService is called` what is `myService` there is nothing declared my service, there is no function called `myService`. And `myDTO.map(MyDTO::getItem) is not getting flattened` i have no idea what you mean here, its not a nested list you can only flatten nested lists so ofc its not flattened. Your question makes no sense and your code makes no sense.

Comment: explain what problem you are trying to solve, then show the code you have written to solve the specific problem. Then post what errors are you getting, what you are expecting to get, and what you are getting instead and why it is the wrong thing. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask voted to close

Comment: I have reworded the question. The intention should be clearer now.

Comment: you cant write `doSomething(tuple.getT2()).then(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok()));` you need a return statement here.

Comment: and also your error message indicates that you are consuming something two times. Since you have not posted more context about what this class is, what is it overriding and what your intention is it is impossible to answer. Im guessing you are reading the body twice somehow, is this a filter or what? we need more context and a small reproducible example.